# Flutter: How to add a Foreground to a dismissable widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a foreground to a dismissible while swipe, Able to set a background . But i need a foreground instead of background?

```
return Dismissible(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    onDismissed: (direction) {
        setState(() {
            model.removeAt(index);
        });
    },
    background: Card(
        elevation: 10,
        child: 
            ext(
                'delete',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                    color: Colors.white
                ),
            ),
    ),

    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Text('ab'),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Improved formatting. Check if brackets are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

[check this library out: flutter_slidable](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable)

By adding 'actions' you can handle the background.The first child of `Slidable` is the foreground and can be altered during a swipe gesture through the use of if-else.